# how can i record date from a function to a datefield

Tags: django, date

i want to record submitted date when the submit button is clicked.
the button is linked to the submit_report view. the rest works perfectly but the date is not recorded

```
#models.ppy
class Report(models.Model):
    createdOn = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    SubmittedOn = models.DateField(auto_now=False, null=True,blank=True)
    userName = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    weekNo = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    projectCode = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    totalAmount = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, 
default_currency='ugx')
    flatsComment = models.CharField(max_length=300, default="")
    financeComment = models.CharField(max_length=300, default="")
    submitted = models.BooleanField(default=False)


#views.py
def submit_report(request, report_id):
    report = get_object_or_404(Report,pk=report_id)
    report.submitted = True
    report.submittedOn = datetime.today()
    report.save()
    return redirect('prog:reports')
```

Comment: Your field is called `SubmittedOn`, not `submittedOn`.

Comment: thank you Daniel, that got me stuck for 20min

Comment: do you know how i can sort the Report list with the most current created date on top of the list?

Comment: i have tried this but it's not working.class ReportView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'prog/report_status.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Report.objects.order_by('createdOn')

Comment: You need `'-createdOn'` for reverse sort.